# Are the terms for upload and download awkward in Esperanto?

Tags: terminology, information-technology

I'm not sure how to formulate this to a question along the Stack Exchange guidelines…

The English words for sending and receiving data to resp. from a server are upload resp. download. You can mentally connect those to an illustration where the server is up and your computer down in a hierarchy. In my native language we use terms that can be translated to sending and receiving. In both cases the perspective is from me, I send up and I receive down.

Is it just me, but I find hard to memorise which way the Esperanto terms *alŝutado* and *elŝutado* are, as if I were looking things from the server's perspective, not mine?

Wouldn't *sendado* and *ricevado* be easier to grasp?

Answer (score 7):

The Esperanto terms seem quite compatible with the mental model in English, if you consider not just the verbs but also the prepositions:

- upload **to** — *al*ŝuti (*to* ≈ *al*)
- download **from** — *el*ŝuti (*from* ≈ *el*)

Even if you ignore the up-down notion missing in Esperanto and use the send-receive model:

- send **to** — *al*ŝuti (*to* ≈ *al*)
- receive **from** — *el*ŝuti (*from* ≈ *el*)

Off course, you can also send something ***from* somewhere** *to* somewhere or receive it *from* somewhere ***to* somewhere**, but as the origin for upload and the destination for download is mostly constant (you, your own computer) while the other side is not, the remote side is the one you usually focus on. The focus can of course be on both, in cases where the specific local directory is of interest.

So I'd say in either language (English and Esperanto), it isn't taking the perspective of the server / remote site. It's simply focusing on it, because that's the variable and thus interesting part.

Comment: (I can only compare Esperanto and English, because I don't know what prepositions or grammatical cases your native language uses with the corresponding verbs.)

Comment: I think that Esperanto captures the down notion. "Ŝuti" involves something going down. Very good answer by the way. I couldn't share what I wanted in a comment, that's why I added another.

Comment: Re: _"Esperanto captures the down notion. 'Ŝuti' involves something going down."_ - Sure, but I feel that _that_ "downwards" is completely unrelated to the "down" in "**down**load". It's more related to the implied "onto" or "into" of "load" in "down**load**". Note that when you load a literal vehicle with baggage, you also usually put that baggage into or onto that vehicle. [Dry bulk cargo](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bulk_cargo&oldid=943817293#Dry_bulk_cargo_(%22dry%22_trades)[9]) (in German: "Schüttgut") is usually loaded from top: It is poured (eo: "ŝuti", de: "schütten").

Answer (score 2):

Notu ke la agoj estas *elŝuto* kaj *alŝuto*. Elŝutado kaj alŝutado signifas nur agadon, ne agon.

Tiu modelo: *al* + radiko verba, *el* + radiko verba, aperas jam en aliaj kunmetaĵoj kaj la signifo, laŭ mi, estas sufiĉe kohera. *Al* povas esti iel aparteniga, ariga kaj *el* liberiga, disiga.

```
Aldoni: post la aldono la afero ne plu estos same memstara, ĝi apartenos al io pli granda.
Eldoni: post la aldono, la libroj estos en vendejoj kaj ne ĉiuj kune en presejo.
```

```
Alpreni: post la preno por si mem, la arigo estas evidenta
Elpreni: oni prenas ion el tuto, iel apartigante tion.
```

Kaj kio do pri *alŝuto/elŝuto*? Oni vidas servilojn kiel grandajn deponejojn, kie aferoj estas kune, arigitaj. Nuntempe eĉ ne servilojn oni rekte rekonas, sed nur servojn aŭ *nubojn*.

Tial la *ariga* *al-* taŭgas en *alŝuti*, ĉar via informo apartenos al io multe pli granda, kune kun amaso da aliaj informoj. Same, la *apartiga el-* taŭgas por tiu elpreno de informoj.

Elŝutoj ne estas tujaj nun kaj ili certe bezonis multe pli da tempo antaŭe. Oni povas facile pensi pri la elglitigo de grenoj el staplo al, ni diru, kamiono. Eĉ modemajn sonojn oni povis aŭdis antaŭe.

Do *ŝuti* rilatas tiun netujan "informglitigon" dum *al* kaj *el* evidentigas la fakton ke tiu ŝuto ne estas simetria ĉar la normala loko por dosieroj en la mondo estis servilo (antaŭe oni apenaŭe alŝutis).

En ciuj lingvoj, kiujn mi povas leg(et)i, elŝuto rilatas ŝargadon. Mi supozas ke ni, esperantoparolantoj, estus povintaj uzi *ŝargi* kaj *malŝargi*. Aŭ nur *transmeti/ŝuti* kaj lasi kuntekston aŭ preposicion klarigi la direkton.

Vi tamen povas diri *mi sendis la dosieron al X* aŭ _mi ricevis la dosieron de X. Oni tuj komprenos.

Jen plurlingvaj tradukoj en Mozilla por [*Download*](https://transvision.mozfr.org/string/?entity=browser/browser/screenshots.ftl:screenshots-download-button&repo=gecko_strings) kaj [*Upload*](https://transvision.mozfr.org/string/?entity=dom/chrome/layout/HtmlForm.properties:DirectoryPickerOkButtonLabel&repo=gecko_strings):